# Quarkus postgresql dev not shutting down

Tags: postgresql, quarkus

Quarkus version is 2.16.5.Final. Datasource is Postgresql. Everything is default wrt dev services except the below settings:

```
quarkus.datasource.devservices.port=5432
```

I run the app using `mvn quarkus:dev`. When I shutdown or kill the server the Postgresql container continues to run (It used to shutdown cleanly along with the server before). I have to manually stop the container every time I want to start the server again.

Comment: This sounds like a bug...

Comment: you can change this behaviour by adding the following to `~/.testcontainers`:  testcontainers.reuse.enable=false